# How to group columns together based on commonality in name, create a combined new column, eliminating NAs?

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have some data similar to this example data, where columns stand for years:

```
data <- data.frame(
  X2020_1 = c("A", NA, "B"),
  X2020_2 = c("A", "C", NA),
  X2021_1 = c("A", NA, "C"),
  X2021_2 = c(NA, NA, "A")
)
```

which looks like this:

```
  X2020_1 X2020_2 X2021_1 X2021_2
1       A       A       A    <NA>
2    <NA>       C    <NA>    <NA>
3       B    <NA>       C       A
```

I want to group the data by columns based on the column name. I want anything with `X2020` in its name to be in a new `X2020` column, and anything with `X2021` to be in a new `X2021` column. I also want to eliminate `NA` values unless there are only `NA`s in that column-group.

My desired end result data should look like this:

```
    X2020   X2021
1 c(A, A)       A
2       C    <NA>
3       B c(C, A)
```

I'm not really sure how to get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two solutions, the first one is more manual and the second one is more dynamic.

#### unite()

From the `tidyr` package, there's an `unite()` function that allows you to combine multiple columns into a single one. But that requires one `unite` function per pattern (or year in this case).

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  unite("X2020", starts_with("X2020"), na.rm = T, sep = ", ") %>% 
  unite("X2021", starts_with("X2021"), na.rm = T, sep = ", ") %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(.x == "", NA, .x)))
```

#### Reshape data

For the second solution, you can first reshape your data into a "long" format, then `summarise` the column per row number and "year" to concatenate the values, and reshape back to "wide" format.

This is more dynamic and do not require hard-coding patterns.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-rn) %>% 
  mutate(name = sub("_\\d", "", name)) %>% 
  group_by(name, rn) %>% 
  summarize(value = toString(na.omit(value))) %>%
  pivot_wider() %>% 
  select(-rn) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(.x == "", NA, .x)))
```

#### Output

Both solutions give the same output.

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  X2020 X2021
  <chr> <chr>
1 A, A  A    
2 C     NA   
3 B     C, A
```

Comment: The first solution is so elegant. Def gonna add `unite()` to my toolbox.